# A movie with giant lampreys (snake-like sea creatures) attacking a boat

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I'm trying to remember the name of a (somewhat horror) movie in which some people get somehow stranded in a boat , and as usuall, things go wrong.

The main plot is that some giant lampreys (snake-like sea creatures) attack the crew.

[image]

There is not much to say about the plot, other than the creatures are big ass lampreys, and the usual "everyone gets killed one at a time" of this kind of movies.

I estimate it is a 90's movie.

SPOILERS from here on

> at the end, only a few members get it out of the ship, and manage to get to a nearby island, only to realize that they landed on a lamprey infested place. The movie ends with a birds view of such island, and we hear monstruous noises and trees moving around as if they are attacking each other...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Deep Rising](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118956/): the creatures you describe as 'Lampreys' are actually semi autonomous tentacles which are the appendages of a giant sea-creature, which is implied to be a prehistoric monster.

[image]

> Finnegan and Trillian use the jet ski to travel to the nearby island,
>   where they are soon joined by Joey. He survived the attack and escaped
>   to the island using Finnegan's surfboard. As the three relax, a loud
>   roar echoes across the island and something crashes toward them
>   through the nearby forest while the camera pans out to reveal multiple
>   active volcanoes within the island. An exasperated Finnegan mutters,
>   "Now what?"

Comment: yay! this is it! thank you very much. I didn't remember it being tentacles of a bigger creature =P thanks!